# Google Cloud ssh key error - python script

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I have a Python script that I'm trying to run on a Google Cloud Compute Engine. I have Jupyter Notebooks setup and running on the Compute Engine and when I connect to it and run the SFTP connection script from a Notebook window on my laptop connecting to the Compute Engine instance, it runs OK.

When I run the same script through the command line directly on the Compute Engine I get an SSH error.

```
(2018-06-15 12:39:52; transport.py:1636) DEBUG:paramiko.transport: Adding ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 host key for sftp.############.com: b'ff97f###################'

(2018-06-15 12:39:52; transport.py:1636) DEBUG:paramiko.transport: Trying SSH agent key b'bc574#######################'

(2018-06-15 12:39:52; transport.py:1636) DEBUG:paramiko.transport: userauth is OK

(2018-06-15 12:39:52; transport.py:1636) INFO:paramiko.transport: Authentication (publickey) failed.

(2018-06-15 12:39:52; transport.py:1636) INFO:paramiko.transport: Disconnect (code 7): Bad service id

(2018-06-15 12:39:53; get_file_sftp.py:29) ERROR:__main__: SFTP Connection: Connection Error
```

I have tried generating a key using

```
ssh-keygen hostname
```

and it created an ECDSA key, but now when I do a regular ssh connection from the command line (which was working before I started messing with keygen) I get the error "shell request failed on channel 0", so I've made things worse and the code still doesn't run.

Doing a ssh-keyscan for the hostname returns two records, one RSA and one ECDSA

Here is my Python code

```
import paramiko
from parse_config import fn_parse_config
from configparser import ConfigParser
import logging
import logging.config
import datetime

def fn_get_file_sftp():

    #initialise logging function
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
    logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

    #get details from config files
    sftp_params = fn_parse_config("etl_process.ini", "remote_sftp")
    sftp_folders = fn_parse_config("etl_process.ini", "sftp_folders")

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    #print('start')
    try:
        logger.info("SFTP Connection:Send credentials")

        ssh.connect(**sftp_params)
        logger.info("SFTP Connection:SUCCESS")

    except paramiko.SSHException:
        logger.error("SFTP Connection: Connection Error")


    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    #sftp.chdir("/vivobarefoot/")
    print (sftp.listdir("/"))

    for file in sftp.listdir("/"):
        sftp.get(remotepath = sftp_folders.get('remote_path') + file, localpath=sftp_folders.get('local_path')  + file )
        logger.info("RETRIEVED SFTP FILE: " + file)
        sftp.remove(sftp_folders.get('remote_path') + file)
        logger.info("REMOVED SFTP FILE: " + file)
    ssh.close()
    logger.info("SFTP Connection:CLOSED")

fn_get_file_sftp()
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the solution, it came from this, running the command

```
gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME
```

Doin this created the SSH key files required by the Python script - so no changes required to the Python code. I still get the error "shell request failed on channel 0" if I try to run a basic ssh connection in the command line in Ubuntu, so when I was trying to do it through Unix commands I clearly broke something, but my main requirement was to get the python script working.

========================
Here is the source of the information I used to find this fix

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/PXEzoZQpcSo

1. add a rule to GCE firewall : $ gcloud compute firewall-rules create mySSH --allow tcp:22 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0
2. test the rule by telnetting : $ telnet IP 22
3. if telnet is working, than SSH is accepting connections, so try to ssh : $ gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME